# How do I securely sign PDF documents without buying a certificate from a CA?

Tags: security, pdf, ssl, certificate, adobe-acrobat

I use Acrobat DC and there's an option for digital signature. From what I've read, I need to purchase a certificate from a CA as self-signed certificates are not secure. What about OpenPGP? Are there any other alternatives?

Seems a bit weird that I have a pay to prove my identity. I understand that it makes a lot of sense for big companies. But what about for personal use?

Comment: Self signed certs are just as secure as a "bought" one. The difference is, people won't have your public key and won't be able to verify it. If you use a self signed cert, you need to transfer your public key to whoever is going to verify your PDF.

Comment: @Panki That's factually inaccurate... a self-signed PEM is not secure, as there's no Chain of Trust... if wanting a code signing PEM, create a self-signed CA and use that to sign the cert, then concatenate the CA's public cert to the signing cert.  Another option would be a GPG key

Comment: What certificate you need depends on who should be able to verify the signature. OpenPGP is not an option as their certificates are not in X509 format and therefore incompatible to the in-PDF signature system. Of course you can still sign the PDF file like any other file using OpenPGP (detached signature in separate file).